# convert auto height of TR to pixel or percentate

Tags: css, height

Is anyone know how to convert the height of TR element which is in AUTO to pixel or percentage?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean at run time using JS or in the development phase?

You could always use the *ruler* made available in the Web Developer tool bar to measure it, and then use that value in your CSS.

Or, any calculating using JS for the height of a tr element should return it in pixels.

Comment: In ie6 this doesn't work until after the document is displayed.  Before that, the height has a value of 'auto'.

Answer (score 1):

using jquery its trivial.

```
  myTrHeight = $("#myTr").height()
```

that will give you the height in pixels.

Comment: This doesn't work.  As the question said, it has a value of 'auto'

Comment: Actually this does work in most browsers, but not in IE6.  I tried it.  :)